# Restrict entry to account for developer

Tags: customer-account, magento-go

We want to hire a developer for our current Magento Go site, which we have to now migrate out of.

We want to give them access such that they do not have control over the shop w logins etc, but yet, can do the coding to the site. Is there a way to give that kind of limited access without giving them control of the account? We don't want them to lock us out.

Thanks so much for your thots.

or, what are the options for access to a Magento go account?

Answer (score 3):

As a developer who has had a difficult time working on sites because of policies such as yours, my best advice is to give the developer full access.

If you cannot trust the developer you are working with to a point where this policy is warranted, my next best advice would be to fire them and hire a developer you can trust. Would you hire a plumber and then tell them they aren't allowed in your bathroom?

If the developer is able to "do the coding to the site", they are by definition already given access to the inner workings of the platform. Putting an artificial restriction on their access to things they are working on is only going to build contempt and waste their time.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for taking the time to write this, pspahn and David for editing the question.

What about 'potential developers' that want to look in the magento go back-end in order to give you an estimate of price of how likely it is that they can make the new shop look like the old shop? 

What do you think?